# How to continue table row on next page when it is too tall?

Tags: tables, longtable, landscape, xltabular

I am using the `xltabular` package to create tables that span several pages (in a landscape environment) It works fine and puts new rows on the next page if they would go off the end of the current page. However, I sometimes have *single* rows that are longer than the actual height of the page, because one of the columns I am using often have a lot of information. This is the case no matter if I use a landscape environment or not.

Here is an example, with the actual text replaced with mock information. I tried to copy only the relevant information from my `.sty` files into this example code:

```latex
% ========== Document Metadata ========== %
% Document structure and setup
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % Paper size
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Text encoding
\usepackage{helvet} % Document font
\usepackage[tmargin=1cm, lmargin=2.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.3cm, headheight=26pt, includeheadfoot]{geometry} % Margins
\usepackage{hyperref} % Allow hyperlinks using \href{}
\linespread{1.1}

% Tables
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}

% Header/footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength\headheight{42pt} % Just to make warning go away. Adjust the value after looking into the warning.
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove hr from fancyhdr
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}} % Remove section number from fancyhdr

% Lists
\usepackage{enumitem} % Reduce space between list items
\setlist{nolistsep} % Reduce space between list items

\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[acronym, nopostdot]{glossaries} 
\usepackage{expl3}

\usepackage{xltabular}
\title{some title}

% ========== Title Page ========== %
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

Table example:

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|p{0.075\linewidth}|p{0.03\linewidth}|p{0.175\linewidth}|p{0.65\linewidth}|} \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} \\ \hline \endhead 
% ---------- New row ---------- %
  Example

  & 
  \incrementStep

  & 
  example

  & 
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
    \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
  \end{enumerate}
  \\\hline
% ---------- New row ---------- %
% 
Example2

& 
\incrementStep

& 
example2

& 
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Here there will be a lot of text and the row breaks the page.
\end{enumerate}
\\\hline
\end{xltabular}



\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

I am compiling this with `pdflatex` and the output (page 2 and 3) looks like this:
[image: pages 2 and 3 out output from the LaTeX provided]

As you can see, the final column may have, for example, a long list in it. In this case, the row is too tall for the page and does not continue on this page. I am fully aware that one solution is to just stop the row earlier, but this feels hacky and I choose to hope that using LaTeX to write my documents will provide me with a way to make them the way I want.

Not sure if it matters, but I am compiling using `pdflatex`.

Comment: this can not be breaked. Split the items over singular rows.

Comment: Ok, is there not any other package in latex which is able to do what I am asking?